# How to pass variable name while reading from Groovy Config file?

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy and here is my question

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper().
parse(new File('RegionConfig.groovy').toURI().toURL())
```

Now i need something like

```
for(String name : listOfNames){
println(config.name)
}
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Do you have simple example input and expected output?  What problem are you having?

Comment: What does RegionConfig contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

config.groovy:

```
user.name='koji'
user.nation='japan'
a.b.c='foo'
```

test code:

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('config.groovy').toURL())
assert ['user.name', 'user.nation', 'a.b.c'] == config.flatten().keySet().collect {it as String}
```

also you can write like follows:

```
for (String name: config.flatten().keySet()) {
    println name
}
```